# ImportError: No module named core - Pycharm with Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

So, I'm studying Django, and when trying to show a index.html, I get this error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named core
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named core
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/Users/witalobenicio/PycharmProjects/Teste',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg',
 '/Users/witalobenicio/PycharmProjects/Teste/$PYTHONPATH',
 '/Users/witalobenicio/PycharmProjects/Teste',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 5 May 2014 17:11:19 +0000
```

Comment: Do you have `django.py` or `django` package anywhere in the project or on the `sys.path`?

Comment: I have Django installed on python, so when i install PyCharm it automatically sets Django for development.

Comment: Python and django are different packages and django doesn't come as built-in in python as far as I know. Try to install django again. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/

Comment: But if in python i do: - import django - it works fine..

Comment: Make sure that you have django installed on the right path

>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 2, 'final', 0)
>>> django.__path__
['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django']
>>>

Comment: Yes...i have django installed.

Comment: Im able to use all the comands of django, i can run a server, my problema is that when it going to show my index.html i have the error above.

Comment: Make sure to uninstall distribute @WitaloBenicio, setuptools should completely replace it, not be next to it. Hopefully `pip uninstall distribute` might work.

Comment: Thanks @ivo but i already solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in urls.py.

I had this regular expression:

```
url(r'^$', 'Teste.core.views.home', name='home'),
```

but i have to use:

```
url(r'^$', 'core.views.home', name='home'),
```

Comment: Please [accept your answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that it's clear that this question has been answered.